# Where can I download the Django documentation?

Tags: python, django, documentation

Django's website seems good but for some reason I couldn't find where to download the documentation:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/

(Yes, I need the docs for 1.1)

Does anyone know?

Comment: https://readthedocs.org/projects/django/downloads/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable in the right sidebar, bottom

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Django's documentation is built using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) and [included in their source tree](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/docs).

From a checked-out copy of Django's source, just run `make` in the docs directory.  You can find instructions for getting the source here: http://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Comment: The `Makefile` is only there for convenience.  If you have Sphinx installed, you can just invoke the `sphinx-build` executable directly where you would make.  `sphinx-build help` will list the arguments, and you can look at the `Makefile` to see what Django would use: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/docs/Makefile

Comment: Also, you could always use Cygwin, but I assume that's not what you want to do ;)

Comment: Okay, I just did it manually using sphinx-build. It was a pretty bad experience. (I had to figure out how the makefile works, and there appears to have been a small error there that I managed to fix.) I just want to say that I don't think it's very Pythonic that you have to go through all this just to have an offline copy of the documentation. I hope that someone will make a better solution.

Comment: Sphinx does have the ability to export PDFs, etc.  I don't know if it's ever been proposed that the Django website host these artifacts, but if that's a need of yours maybe you should.

Comment: Note that for django 1.3 default "make html" fails on Windows as the Makefile appears to not specify the sourcedir for docs; you can use "sphinx-build . _build" to make the default documentation.

Comment: Cygwin default install doesn't currently include "make"... yes you can add it, but if it involves installing the whole of the C language this will seriously bloat your Cygwin files (e.g. by 1+ GB)... seems a bit mad just to create documentation.  This said, it's a shame: I always like to generate my offline docs from the source if possible.  On Windoze I'd recommend maciek's solution.

Comment: See @maciek's answer for easily just downloading it.

Answer (score 18):

Offline Documentation for Django **1.2**, **1.3** and **1.4** in various formats:

http://readthedocs.org/projects/django/downloads/

Comment: There is a direct link on the docs.djangoproject.com sidebar the last time I looked at it! (and a kindly mark of "provided by Read The Docs")

Comment: This version is horrible, a 16MB html file that takes ages to load. @maciek answer downloads a much better (original) (not computer parsed and regenerated version).

Answer (score 10):

You can download offline documentation for Django 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 in both PDF and HTML from http://sramana.github.com/dod/.

Comment: The link is 404

Answer (score 4):

In the bottom of right sidebar there are links to zipped HTML version, PDF version and ePub version.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/

Comment: I just could not find it on django's site, thanks so much! The readthedocs version I found online was one giant 16MB html file that took ages to load, this version is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

*"Okay, I just did it manually using sphinx-build. It was a pretty bad experience."*

Hmm. I just tried and it was a pretty smooth experience (and I have never done this before).  Here's the Linux recipe:

1. "cd" to the directory where your Django 1.2.x download has been extracted (in my case "~/downloads/Django-1.2.1")
2. cd docs
3. make latex PAPER=a4
4. cd _build/latex
5. make all-pdf

And the end result is 1000 page tome of Django goodness!

Comment: A "pretty smooth experience" would be to click a "download documentation" link on Django's website.

Comment: Agreed.  Why not post this as a request to the mailing list or on the tracking system?

Comment: If you google: "django 1.2 documentation  filetype:pdf" (that's how I found this thread :)) you're pretty likely to find something out there on the internet (though I found i did need to look around a little). 

here's 1.2: http://pub.xupisco.net/django_docs-1.2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To generate PDF version in Ubuntu, you need to download 700-900 MB of Latex packages.
Even if you are not in a developing country, keeping a local copy of docs is useful. Just in case the Django site is down or when you need to refer to something while traveling.Django docs are written in ReStructuredText (RST) and you need Sphinx tool to generate HTML version
http://sramana.github.com/dod/